# How to return rows with 0 count for missing data?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, left-join, generate-series

I have unevenly distributed data (wrt `date`) for a few years (2003-2008). I want to query data for a given set of start and end date, grouping the data by any of the supported intervals (day, week, month, quarter, year) in [PostgreSQL 8.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC).

The problem is that some of the queries give results continuous over the required period, as this one:

```
select to_char(date_trunc('month',date), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), count(distinct post_id) 
from some_table
where category_id = 1
and entity_id = 77
and entity2_id = 115 
and date <= '2008-12-06'
and date >= '2007-12-01'
group by date_trunc('month',date)
order by date_trunc('month',date);

  to_char   | count 
------------+-------
 2007-12-01 |    64
 2008-01-01 |    31
 2008-02-01 |    14
 2008-03-01 |    21
 2008-04-01 |    28
 2008-05-01 |    44
 2008-06-01 |   100
 2008-07-01 |    72
 2008-08-01 |    91
 2008-09-01 |    92
 2008-10-01 |    79
 2008-11-01 |    65
(12 rows)
```

But some of them miss some intervals because there is no data present, as this one:

```
select to_char(date_trunc('month',date), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), count(distinct post_id) 
from some_table
where category_id=1
and entity_id = 75
and entity2_id = 115 
and date <= '2008-12-06'
and date >= '2007-12-01'
group by date_trunc('month',date)
order by date_trunc('month',date);
    
  to_char   | count 
------------+-------

 2007-12-01 |     2
 2008-01-01 |     2
 2008-03-01 |     1
 2008-04-01 |     2
 2008-06-01 |     1
 2008-08-01 |     3
 2008-10-01 |     2
(7 rows)
```

where the required resultset is:

```
  to_char   | count 
------------+-------
 2007-12-01 |     2
 2008-01-01 |     2
 2008-02-01 |     0
 2008-03-01 |     1
 2008-04-01 |     2
 2008-05-01 |     0
 2008-06-01 |     1
 2008-07-01 |     0
 2008-08-01 |     3
 2008-09-01 |     0
 2008-10-01 |     2
 2008-11-01 |     0
(12 rows)
```

A count of 0 for missing entries.

I have seen earlier discussions on Stack Overflow but they don't solve my problem it seems, since my grouping period is one of (day, week, month, quarter, year) and decided on runtime by the application. So an approach like left join with a calendar table or sequence table will not help I guess.

My current solution to this is to fill in these gaps in Python (in a Turbogears App) using the calendar module.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create the list of all first days of the last year (say) with

```
select distinct date_trunc('month', (current_date - offs)) as date 
from generate_series(0,365,28) as offs;
          date
------------------------
 2007-12-01 00:00:00+01
 2008-01-01 00:00:00+01
 2008-02-01 00:00:00+01
 2008-03-01 00:00:00+01
 2008-04-01 00:00:00+02
 2008-05-01 00:00:00+02
 2008-06-01 00:00:00+02
 2008-07-01 00:00:00+02
 2008-08-01 00:00:00+02
 2008-09-01 00:00:00+02
 2008-10-01 00:00:00+02
 2008-11-01 00:00:00+01
 2008-12-01 00:00:00+01
```

Then you can join with that series.

Comment: I tried this :    http://pastebin.com/f6f44e58b
still 7 rows. Is there something wrong with the join

Comment: Though I think the (start, stop , step) have to be carefully filled before doing the query and i skeptic that for a long enough period the step of 28 can fail, what do you think?

Comment: Stepping in steps of 28 days will always hit every month at least once, since the shortest months is 28 days; feel free to use any smaller step, though. It will hit the same month twice occasionally, hence the DISTINCT filter.

Comment: I wish you hadn't deleted the pastebin for the correct answer  :(

Answer (score 37):

<sup>This question is old. But since fellow users picked it as master for a new duplicate I am adding a proper answer.</sup>

#### Proper solution

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT day::date
   FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2007-12-01'
                        , timestamp '2008-12-01'
                        , interval  '1 month') day
   ) d
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT date_trunc('month', date_col)::date AS day
        , count(*) AS some_count
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  date_col >= date '2007-12-01'
   AND    date_col <= date '2008-12-06'
-- AND    ... more conditions
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) t USING (day)
ORDER  BY day;
```

Use `LEFT JOIN`, of course.

[`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) can produce a table of timestamps on the fly, and very fast. See:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

It's typically faster to aggregate *before* you join. Related answer with test case in a fiddle:

- [PostgreSQL - order by an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664373/postgresql-order-by-an-array/15674585#15674585)

Cast the `timestamp` to `date` (`::date`) for a basic format. For more use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).

`GROUP BY 1` is syntax shorthand to reference the first output column. Could be `GROUP BY day` as well, but that might conflict with an existing column of the same name. Or `GROUP BY date_trunc('month', date_col)::date` but that's too long for my taste.

Works with the available interval arguments for [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC).

[`count()` never returns `NULL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) - `0` for no rows - but the `LEFT JOIN` does.
To return `0` instead of `NULL` in the outer `SELECT`, use `COALESCE(some_count, 0) AS some_count`. [The manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)

For a **more generic solution or arbitrary time intervals** see:

- [Best way to count rows by arbitrary time intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576794/best-way-to-count-records-by-arbitrary-time-intervals-in-railspostgres/15577413#15577413)

Comment: is it possible to accomplish this with CTEs?

Comment: @zam6ak: Sure, in various ways. But why would you want to? A CTE would be slower. Use CTEs only when you need them in Postgres. If you have a use case, I suggest asking a new question. You can always link to this answer for context and drop a comment here which links to the related question and notifies me.

Comment: Thanks, I posted a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332433/pg-how-to-include-missing-data-for-multiple-groupings-including-time-span)

Comment: This query is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for the answer. Is there a way to have some_count return 0 and not empty data?

Comment: @Paul: I added instructions in the answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I am using `COALESCE(count(*), 0) AS click_count` however it is still an empty value. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Paul: Yes, you are missing the essential part. `COALESCE(count(*), 0)` *never* makes sense. I wrote: *in the outer `SELECT` use `COALESCE(some_count, 0) AS some_count`*. `count(*)` happens in the subquery before the `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary table at runtime and left join on that.  That seems to make the most sense.

Comment: sorry I don't have time to look into the actual feasibility