# Aggregate a single column in query with many columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Is there a proper way to aggregate a single column when I have many other columns in the query?

I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43944/1331430) which works, but my query has become a lot more verbose.

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT t1.foo1, t1.foo2, t2.foo3, t2.foo4, string_agg(t3.aggregated_field, ', ')
FROM tbl1 t1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.fkeyid
LEFT JOIN tbl3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.fkeyid
GROUP BY t1.foo1, t1.foo2, t2.foo3, t2.foo4, t2.foo5, t2.foo6
ORDER BY t2.foo5, t2.foo6
```

The query has many more fields and `LEFT JOIN`s, the important part is that all these fields have 1 to 1 or 1 to 0 relationship except one field that is 1 to n which I want to aggregate, represented by `t3.aggregated_field` in the pseudo-query above.

As I'm using an aggregate function, all fields listed in the `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` must be either aggregated or part of the `GROUP BY` clause. This makes my query way more verbose than it already is.

That is, assuming `foo1` is a primary key, when this field is repeated, all others except `aggregated_field` are also equal. I want these repeated rows as a single row result with the aggregated field value. (basically a `select distinct` with an aggregated column)

Is there a better way to do this (without having to put all other fields in the `GROUP BY`) or should I just iterate over the result set in my back-end executing a query for each row fetching this 1 to n relationship?

---

The server is running PostgreSQL 9.1.9, more specifically:

> PostgreSQL 9.1.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54), 64-bit

Comment: Why would a developer *not* disclose the version of the software he is asking about. Why? It's a painful mass phenomenon here on SO. It's like otherwise highly intelligent people turn into dummies immediately once they ask a question. Supply your software version with your question. **This should go without saying.**

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter My bad, the version is 9.0+, I'll connect to server's network so I can check the exact version before I add to the question.

Comment: Thanks. My comment is the result of frustration that has been building. It should be so obvious. And yet, so many people don't think of it. Even high-reputation folks. BTW, 9.1 - you go lucky there. My answer should work for you.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, I understand. Though the use of `string_agg` implicitly makes it a pgsql9+, I should know better than minor versions have significant changes and I admit it was laziness on my part to not check the version beforehand. Skimming through answer makes perfect sense, I'll provide feedback in an hour or so when I have the time to apply and test it. `=]`

Comment: BTW, major versions include first digit after the dot in PostgreSQL. [More on the official versioning site of the project.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter damn my stupidity. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Simple query

This can be **much simpler** with PostgreSQL **9.1 or later**. As explained in this closely related answer:

- [PGError: ERROR: aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause on a AR query of an object and its has_many objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684486/rails-3-getting-a-pgerror-error-aggregates-not-allowed-in-where-clause-on-a-a/8684512#8684512)

It is enough to `GROUP BY` the *primary key* of a table. Since:

> foo1 is a primary key

.. you can simplify your example to:

```
SELECT foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5, foo6, string_agg(aggregated_field, ', ')
FROM   tbl1
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY foo7, foo8;  -- have to be spelled out, since not in select list!
```

#### Query with multiple tables

However, since you have:

> many more fields and LEFT JOINs, the important part is that all these  fields have 1 to 1 or 1 to 0 relationship except one field that is 1 to n which I want to aggregate

.. it should be faster and simpler to **aggregate first, join later**:

```
SELECT t1.foo1, t1.foo2, ...
     , t2.bar1, t2.bar2, ...
     , a.aggregated_col 
FROM   tbl1 t1
LEFT   JOIN tbl2 t2 ON ...
...
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT some_id, string_agg(agg_col, ', ') AS aggregated_col
   FROM   agg_tbl a ON ...
   GROUP  BY some_id
   ) a ON a.some_id = ?.some_id
ORDER  BY ...
```

This way the big portion of your query does not need aggregation at all.

I recently provided a test case in an SQL Fiddle to prove the point in this related answer:

- [PostgreSQL - order by an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664373/postgresql-order-by-an-array/15674585#15674585)

Since you are referring to [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1777448/1331430): No, `DISTINCT` is not going to help at all in this case.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the `DISTINCT` wouldn't help in this case a couple hours ago. I'll check your answer throughout when I get home. `=]`

Comment: From my understanding, the sub-query will implicitly create a temporary table with the aggregations of the whole table before the join. In that case I can optimize it a bit if I put a `WHERE` clause in the sub-query, correct? This looks like the best approach, I'll adapt it to my needs. Thanks.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: A WHERE clause may be useful, especially if you have an index that corresponds to it. However, depending on the whole query, the Postgres query planner may use varying plans, whichever it expects to be fastest (that's where properly configured [planner cost constants](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS) come in). It's not necessarily a "temp table" (materialize step). Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to get the details.

Answer (score 1):

If the main problem is that the fields (foox) are computed then this can help:

```
SELECT foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5, foo6, string_agg(aggregated_field, ', ')
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
ORDER BY 5, 6
```

The `1, 2...` are the fields in the order they appear in the select list.

Comment: Though not ideal, I guess this will reduce the verbosity as I asked. Will do some more research this noon.

Comment: Works great, just a note: `foo7` and `foo8` can't be enumerated in that manner unless they were also in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes I just copied and guessed they were in the real select list.

Comment: I'll keep the +1 as it was useful to me, but when you have 30 fields in the select and more in the `ORDER BY` this is not very maintainable. `=]`