# Using a column in sql join without adding it to group by clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

My actual table structures are much more complex but following are two simplified table definitions:

Table `invoice`

```
CREATE TABLE invoice (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  create_datetime timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  total numeric(22,10) NOT NULL
);

id   create_datetime   total    
----------------------------
100  2014-05-08        1000
```

Table `payment_invoice`

```
CREATE TABLE payment_invoice (
  invoice_id integer,
  amount numeric(22,10)
);

invoice_id  amount
-------------------
100         100
100         200
100         150
```

I want to select the data by joining above 2 tables and selected data should look like:-

```
month      total_invoice_count  outstanding_balance
05/2014    1                    550
```

The query I am using:

```
select
to_char(date_trunc('month', i.create_datetime), 'MM/YYYY') as month,
count(i.id) as total_invoice_count,
(sum(i.total) - sum(pi.amount)) as outstanding_balance
from invoice i
join payment_invoice pi on i.id=pi.invoice_id
group by date_trunc('month', i.create_datetime)
order by date_trunc('month', i.create_datetime);
```

Above query is giving me incorrect results as `sum(i.total) - sum(pi.amount)` returns (1000 + 1000 + 1000) - (100 + 200 + 150) = **2550**.
I want it to return (1000) - (100 + 200 + 150) = **550**

And I cannot change it to `i.total - sum(pi.amount)`, because then I am forced to add `i.total` column to group by clause and that I don't want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a single row per invoice, so aggregate `payment_invoice` first - best before you join.
When the whole table is selected, it's typically fastest to [*aggregate first* and *join later*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018237/aggregate-a-single-column-in-query-with-many-columns/16023336#16023336):

```
SELECT to_char(date_trunc('month', i.create_datetime), 'MM/YYYY') AS month
     , count(*)                                   AS total_invoice_count
     , (sum(i.total) - COALESCE(sum(pi.paid), 0)) AS outstanding_balance
FROM   invoice i
LEFT   JOIN  (
    SELECT invoice_id AS id, sum(amount) AS paid
    FROM   payment_invoice pi
    GROUP  BY 1
    ) pi USING (id)
GROUP  BY date_trunc('month', i.create_datetime)
ORDER  BY date_trunc('month', i.create_datetime);
```

[**`LEFT JOIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) is essential here. You do not want to loose invoices that have no corresponding rows in `payment_invoice` (yet), which would happen with a plain `JOIN`.

Accordingly, use [`COALESCE()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) for the sum of payments, which might be NULL.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3eab4/1) with improved test case.

Comment: Thanks a lot Erwin for your reply. In fact I do not have enough words to say thank you :-) I was banging my head against the wall since afternoon. Your solution worked like a magic wand. Thank you!!!

Comment: Hello Erwin, I have one quick follow up question. In your feedback, I can see, we are not mentioning the join needs to be performed on i.id=pi.invoice_id. Just wanted to know does 'pi USING (id)' takes care of that part. Thank you!

Comment: @user238990: As you can see in the fiddle it does. The reason is the column alias in the subquery: `invoice_id` **`AS id`**.

Answer (score 1):

See [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d2524/4)

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(invoice.create_datetime, 'MM/YYYY') as month,
       COUNT(invoice.create_datetime) as total_invoice_count,
       invoice.total - payments.sum_amount as outstanding_balance
FROM invoice
JOIN 
(
    SELECT invoice_id, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount
    FROM payment_invoice
    GROUP BY invoice_id
) payments
ON invoice.id = payments.invoice_id
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(invoice.create_datetime, 'MM/YYYY'), 
         invoice.total - payments.sum_amount
```

Comment: Thank you Tom for taking out time to answer my query. Since Erwin's reply also takes care of the 'no payments for an invoice' scenario I am accepting his feedback as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do the aggregation in two steps. First aggregate to a single line per invoice, then to a single line per month:

```
select
  to_char(date_trunc('month', t.create_datetime), 'MM/YYYY') as month,
  count(*) as total_invoice_count,
  (sum(t.total) - sum(t.amount)) as outstanding_balance
from (
    select i.create_datetime, i.total, sum(pi.amount) amount
    from invoice i
    join payment_invoice pi on i.id=pi.invoice_id
    group by i.id, i.total
) t
group by date_trunc('month', t.create_datetime)
order by date_trunc('month', t.create_datetime);
```

Comment: Hello Torino, I really appreciate your reply. But since Erwin's reply also takes care of the 'no payments for an invoice' scenario I am accepting his feedback as the final answer.