# Select rows with a specific column greater than zero in some related rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance, relational-division

I have the following tables in a Postgres 9.5 database:

**`product_days`**

```
Column     | Type    | Modifiers
-----------+---------+----------------------------------------------
id         | integer | not null default nextval('product_days_id_seq'::regclass)
days_id    | integer |
product_id | integer |
available  | integer | 
price      | integer |
 Indexes:
"pk_product_days" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"idx_product_days" btree (days_id)
"idx_product_days_0" btree (product_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
   "product_days_days_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (days_id) REFERENCES days(id)
```

**`product`**

```
 Column         |            Type             |                       Modifiers
----------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
id              | integer                     | not null default nextval('product_id_seq'::regclass)
name            | character varying(100)      |
number_of_items | integer                     |
created_at      | timestamp without time zone | default now()
updated_at      | timestamp without time zone | default now()
total_number    | integer                     |
 Indexes:
    "pk_product" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

`product_days.product_id` is a foreign key referring to the `product` table and `available` represents the number of products available in each day.

I want to get all products that are available (`available > 0`) at some specific days (`days_id between 5 and 10`). They should be available at *all*  of these days.

Currently I am trying to get the result with the following query but I am not sure whether it is correct or this is the most efficient way to do it:

```
select product.id as p_id, product.name as p_name, product.number_of_items as items
from product_days join product ON product_days.product_id = product.id
WHERE product_days.available > 0
AND  prodcut_days.days_id between 5 and 10
group by product.id
HAVING count(*) > 5;
```

The output should be like:

```
 p_id  | p_name    | items
-------+-----------+-------
 1     | product_1 | 4
 2     | product_2 | 13
```

I need the most efficient way of running this query either in SQL or in plpgsql.

Comment: Please post expected output for some sample data

Comment: @RadimBača I just edited the question please check it again

Comment: I miss the sample data

Comment: Missing: table definition (showing data types and constraints), Postgres version, sample data and the query you tried so far (even if it's not working). And I suppose you mean plpgsql where you mention "pgpsql"?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I have edited the question could you please check it again to see if now enough information is provided

Comment: `product_days.available_unit` is in your query, but not in your table definition. Why `HAVING count(*) > 5`? Please clarify, and clean up the formatting. And no, it's not "plpgpsql", either. It's plpgsql.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I corrected the typos it should be greater than 5 because the product should be available in all 6 days specified by ids between 5 and 10

Comment: I doubt that. `prodcut_days.id between 5 and 10` hardly makes sense for a serial PK column. Maybe you mean `days_id` instead? With all the fuzzy information, you won't get "the most efficient way to do it".

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes I corrected that as well thanks you noticed that

Comment: Also: `HAVING count(*) > 5`. How do you know it's 5 *distinct* days? there is no constraint enforcing unique `(product_id, days_id)`. Should there be?

Comment: Yes it's 5 distinct days I think a constraint should be added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After clarifying the typos, yes, the query should do what you describe.

This is equivalent and a bit faster:

```
SELECT id AS p_id, name AS p_name, number_of_items AS items
FROM  (
   SELECT product_id AS id
   FROM   product_days
   WHERE  available > 0
   AND    days_id BETWEEN 5 AND 10
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING count(*) > 5
   ) d
JOIN  product p USING (id);
```

There should be a [`UNIQUE` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) enforcing max 1 entry per product and day:

```
ALTER TABLE product_days ADD CONSTRAINT your_name_here UNIQUE (product_id, days_id);
```

Related:

- [Using a column in sql join without adding it to group by clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572238/using-a-column-in-sql-join-without-adding-it-to-group-by-clause/23572491#23572491)

### Optimize read performance

If you need to optimize performance for this particular query and there are more than a few non-qualifying rows (not `available` or `day_id` not matching), the sharpest weapon would be a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html):

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name_here ON product_days (product_id)
WHERE  available > 0
AND    days_id BETWEEN 5 AND 10;
```

If you have `autovacuum` running and the write load on the table isn't too big, you should see index-only scans on this index.

And while this index (or a more generic one) is used, this query should be faster, yet:

```
SELECT id AS p_id, name AS p_name, number_of_items AS items
FROM  (
   SELECT product_id AS id
   FROM   product_days d5
   JOIN   product_days d6  USING (product_id)
   JOIN   product_days d7  USING (product_id)
   JOIN   product_days d8  USING (product_id)
   JOIN   product_days d9  USING (product_id)
   JOIN   product_days d10 USING (product_id)
   WHERE  d5.days_id  = 5  AND d5.available  > 0
   AND    d6.days_id  = 6  AND d6.available  > 0
   AND    d7.days_id  = 7  AND d7.available  > 0
   AND    d8.days_id  = 8  AND d8.available  > 0
   AND    d9.days_id  = 9  AND d9.available  > 0
   AND    d10.days_id = 10 AND d10.available > 0   
   ) d
JOIN  product p USING (id);
```

Since this is a case of **[relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division)** at its core. See:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)
- [Arbitrary queries on n:m relationship, including “all” and “any”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194269/arbitrary-queries-on-nm-relationship-including-all-and-any/194333#194333)

Comment: Thanks for your helps I'd try it