# SELECT with sorting and counting by a joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql, eloquent, left-join, aggregate

I'm having hard times with a PostgreSQL `SELECT` that at first looked pretty simple. Involved tables:

```
CREATE TABLE events (id INT, customers_id INT);
CREATE TABLE jobs (
  events_id INT,
  "from"    TIMESTAMP,
  until     TIMESTAMP,
  users_id  INT);
```

- each event can have multiple jobs
- start and end of an event is defined by the lowest `"from"` and the highest `until` of the corresponding jobs
- each job can be assigned to a user

I need a table like the following:

```
events_id | customers_id | min(from) | max(until) | total_jobs | open_jobs
        1 |            1 |  .. 08:00 |   .. 11:00 |          4 |        1
```

My select so far:

```
SELECT e.id, e.customers_id, min(j.from) as min_from, max(j.until) as max_until, 
  count(j.id) as total_jobs
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN jobs j ON j.events_id = e.id
GROUP BY e.id, e.customers_id
```

This gives me the result for the first 5 columns, but how can I include a second count for just the jobs with `users_id = NULL`? I would assume that I need a second `LEFT JOIN` on the jobs table but somehow I can't get it working.

How can I implement that correctly and efficiently?

Comment: What do you mean by a second count for just the jobs with users_id = NULL? What is an open job? jobs that don't have users? ie, You want to know how to calculate open_jobs which is the number of jobs with user_id as null?

Comment: Are you querying for all events (like your query suggests) or for one or few given `events_id`? Please always disclose your Postgres version. `SELECT version()` helps. I took the liberty to fix the syntax of your setup. Reserved words like `from` require double-quoting (except when table-qualified like in `j.from`). And what about the "sorting" you mention in the title?

Comment: @KristjanKica Sorry for not clarifying "open job". I mean the jobs with users_id = NULL

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I'm querying for all events. Postgres version is 10.5. Thank you for your edit. I forgot the sorting, but it is only a `ORDER BY min("from")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While getting all or most events, it's typically fastest (and simplest) to aggregate the n-table *before* the join:

```
SELECT e.id, e.customers_id
     , j.min_from
     , j.max_until
     , j.total_jobs
     , j.open_jobs
FROM   events e
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT events_id    AS id -- alias only to ease join syntax
        , min("from")  AS min_from
        , max(until)   AS max_until
        , count(*)     AS total_jobs
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE users_id IS NULL) AS open_jobs
-- equivalent for old versions:
--      , count(users_id IS NULL OR NULL)          AS open_jobs
   FROM   jobs
   GROUP  BY 1
   )  j USING (id);
```

This way you don't need to `GROUP BY` the 1-table at all.

And since you were considering a second `LEFT JOIN`: If you don't aggregate first, you'd run into a "proxy cross join" situation with this.

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

The aggregate `FILTER` clause requires Postgres 9.4 or later.

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

Related:

- [Aggregate a single column in query with many columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018237/aggregate-a-single-column-in-query-with-many-columns/16023336#16023336)
- [Multiple array_agg() calls in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622398/multiple-array-agg-calls-in-a-single-query/27626358#27626358)

Aside: never use [reserved words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) like `from` as column names, unless you fancy complications ...

Comment: I'll give it a try later. A proxy cross join could be the situation I ran into. `FILTER` looks great, I've never heard of it before.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `open job` definition is `until` is null

```
WITH open_jobs_cte as (select events_id, customer_id, count(*) open_jobs FROM jobs WHERE until is null group by 1,2)
SELECT e.id, e.customers_id, min(j.from) as min_from, max(j.until) as max_until, count(j.id) as total_jobs, open_jobs
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN jobs j ON j.events_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN open_jobs_cte oj ON oj.events_id = e.id
GROUP BY e.id, e.customers_id
```

Based on your requirements/design customer can be excluded from cte

Comment: Sorry, `open job` is a job with `users_id = NULL`. But that can be changed easily. I'll give it a try later when I'm at home. Never heard of `WITH (cte)`, thanks for your answer

Comment: If I remove customer_id (since it's in `events`) and change it to `users_id is null`, it gives me the error `ERROR: column "oj.open_jobs" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming open_jobs is the number of jobs with user_id as null?

```
SELECT e.id, e.customers_id, min(j.from) as min_from, max(j.until) as max_until, 
  count(j.id) as total_jobs,sum(case user_id is null then 1 else 0) as open_jobs
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN jobs j ON j.events_id = e.id
GROUP BY e.id, e.customers_id
```

Notice the `sum(case user_id is null then 1 else 0)`. If the user_id is null then you have an open job, so you add 1, otherwise you add 0.

`EDIT:` Since you also need to sort by min_from, you can

```
select *from
(
SELECT e.id, e.customers_id, min(j.from) as min_from, max(j.until) as max_until, 
  count(j.id) as total_jobs,sum(case user_id is null then 1 else 0) as open_jobs
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN jobs j ON j.events_id = e.id
GROUP BY e.id, e.customers_id
) as results 
order by min_from
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll give it a try later when I'm at home.