# Multiply an array from a column with the result of a count from another query

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions

I am new to Postgres and databases so I am sorry. I ran a query to get a count of students per school from one table. Now I have the table below:

```
school_probs:

school_code(PK bigint)  schoolName(text)    probs(numeric)
1                       CAA             {0.05,0.08,0.18,0.3,0.11,0.28}
2                       CAS             {0.06,0.1,0.295,0.36,0.12,0.065}
3                       CBA             {0.05,0.11,0.35,0.32,0.12,0.05}
4                       CL              {0.07,0.09,0.24,0.4,0.06,0.09}
```

How would I go about multiplying the count from each school with each number in the probs column. Ex: We have total number of students at school "CAA" If it is 198, then the probability distribution will be
`(0.05*198, 0.08*198, 0.18*198, 0.3*198, 0.11*198, 0.28*198)`. With the results I can then assign grades to students.

My query to get the count is as follows:

```
SELECT simulated_records.school, COUNT(simulated_records.school) as studentCount INTO CountSchool
FROM simulated_records, school_probs
WHERE simulated_records.school = school_probs.school
GROUP BY simulated_records.school;
```

Comment: Please remember to always declare your version of Postgres. The data type is `numeric[]`, not `numeric`, btw.

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/3404097)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To multiply elements of an array with a constant, you need to unnest, multiply, and aggregate again. Some caveats lie in wait. Consider:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

And best use an [ARRAY constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS).

That said, and making some assumptions about your undisclosed table design, I would also simplify the count:

- [Aggregate a single column in query with many columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018237/aggregate-a-single-column-in-query-with-many-columns/16023336#16023336)

Arriving at:

```
SELECT *, ARRAY(SELECT unnest(p.probs) * r.student_ct) AS scaled_probs
FROM   school_probs p
LEFT   JOIN  (
   SELECT school, COUNT(*)::int AS student_ct
   FROM   simulated_records
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) r USING (school);
```

Or, to represent NULL arrays as NULL arrays:

```
SELECT *
FROM   school_probs p
LEFT   JOIN  (
   SELECT school, COUNT(*)::int AS student_ct
   FROM   simulated_records
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) r USING (school)
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(SELECT unnest(p.probs) * r.student_ct) AS scaled_probs
   ) p1 ON p.probs IS NOT NULL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=88439019ec2572b0348c15d1fdc6348e)*

I suggest this simply form with a set-returning function in the SELECT list only for Postgres 10 or later, because of:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in select clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

Comment: Perfect thank you! What I was looking for. How you would I round the results to be whole figures?

Comment: A simple cast (after the multiplication!) should do the job. `(unnest(probs) * 198)::int)`. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=dbbd9821f590b0a8902b69c7fdf7ced5