# Why does the following join increase the query time significantly?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions, postgresql-performance

I have a star schema here and I am querying the fact table and would like to join one very small dimension table. I can't really explain the following:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT 
  COUNT(impression_id), imp.os_id 
  FROM bi.impressions imp 
  GROUP BY imp.os_id;

                                                                  QUERY PLAN
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     HashAggregate  (cost=868719.08..868719.24 rows=16 width=10) (actual time=12559.462..12559.466 rows=26 loops=1)
       ->  Seq Scan on impressions imp  (cost=0.00..690306.72 rows=35682472 width=10) (actual time=0.009..3030.093 rows=35682474 loops=1)
     Total runtime: 12559.523 ms
    (3 rows)
```

This takes ~12600ms, but of course there is no joined data, so I can't "resolve" the imp.os_id to something meaningful, so I add a join:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT 
  COUNT(impression_id), imp.os_id, os.os_desc 
  FROM  bi.impressions imp, bi.os_desc os 
  WHERE imp.os_id=os.os_id 
  GROUP BY imp.os_id, os.os_desc;
                                                                     QUERY PLAN
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     HashAggregate  (cost=1448560.83..1448564.99 rows=416 width=22) (actual time=25565.124..25565.127 rows=26 loops=1)
       ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.58..1180942.29 rows=35682472 width=22) (actual time=0.046..15157.684 rows=35682474 loops=1)
             Hash Cond: (imp.os_id = os.os_id)
             ->  Seq Scan on impressions imp  (cost=0.00..690306.72 rows=35682472 width=10) (actual time=0.007..3705.647 rows=35682474 loops=1)
             ->  Hash  (cost=1.26..1.26 rows=26 width=14) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=26 loops=1)
                   Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2kB
                   ->  Seq Scan on os_desc os  (cost=0.00..1.26 rows=26 width=14) (actual time=0.003..0.010 rows=26 loops=1)
     Total runtime: 25565.199 ms
    (8 rows)
```

This effectively doubles the execution time of my query. My question is, what did I leave out from the picture? I would think such a small lookup was not causing huge difference in query execution time.

Comment: do you have indexes on both `impressions.os_id` and `os.os_id` ?

Comment: Indexes would probably yield a bitmask index scan (though, without a sufficiently selective WHERE clause,all the rows would be needed anyway, presuming impression_id is not in any index)

Comment: Yes both has indexes (btree (os_id))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewritten with (recommended) explicit ANSI JOIN syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT(impression_id), imp.os_id, os.os_desc 
FROM   bi.impressions imp
JOIN   bi.os_desc os ON os.os_id = imp.os_id
GROUP  BY imp.os_id, os.os_desc;
```

First of all, your second query *might* be wrong, if more or less than exactly one match are found in `os_desc` for every row in impressions.
This can be ruled out if you have a *foreign key constraint* on `os_id` in place, that guarantees referential integrity, plus a *`NOT NULL` constraint* on `bi.impressions.os_id`. If so, in a first step, simplify to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ct, imp.os_id, os.os_desc 
FROM   bi.impressions imp
JOIN   bi.os_desc     os USING (os_id)
GROUP  BY imp.os_id, os.os_desc;
```

`count(*)` is faster than `count(column)` and equivalent here if the column is `NOT NULL`. And add a column alias for the count.

**Faster, yet:**

```
SELECT os_id, os.os_desc, sub.ct
FROM  (
   SELECT os_id, COUNT(*) AS ct
   FROM   bi.impressions
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
JOIN   bi.os_desc os USING (os_id)
```

Aggregate first, join later. More here:

- [Aggregate a single column in query with many columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018237/aggregate-a-single-column-in-query-with-many-columns/16023336#16023336)
- [PostgreSQL - order by an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664373/postgresql-order-by-an-array/15674585#15674585)

Comment: Thanks Erwin, I am running explain analyze on these to understand the performance impact also reading the docs what you have linked.

Comment: Erwin, your query wins, thank you! Also thank you for the documentation. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
HashAggregate  (cost=868719.08..868719.24 rows=16 width=10)
HashAggregate  (cost=1448560.83..1448564.99 rows=416 width=22)
```

Hmm, width from 10 to 22 is a doubling.  Perhaps you should join after grouping instead of before?

Comment: Hey David, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The following query solves the problem without increasing the query execution time. The question still stands why does the execution time increase significantly with adding a very simple join, but it might be a Postgres specific question and somebody with extensive experience in the area might answer it eventually.

```
WITH 
  OSES AS (SELECT os_id,os_desc from bi.os_desc) 
SELECT 
  COUNT(impression_id) as imp_count, 
  os_desc FROM bi.impressions imp, 
  OSES os 
WHERE 
  os.os_id=imp.os_id 
GROUP BY os_desc 
ORDER BY imp_count;
```

Comment: Doing work takes time.  Doing more works takes more time.  A simple join is still work that must be done.  By grouping by two things rather than one, you impose more work on it.  BTW, the above query can be better written without the WITH by just incorporating the bi.os_desc directly into query.  The key to the increased speed is not the with, it is removing a needless column from the GROUP BY.