# Finding out the total count of each tag in a data set

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, many-to-many, aggregate-functions

I have a set of `Item`-s and each of them has a set of `Tag`-s. I want to have a DB SELECT which, for some (large) subset of these items, returns the total count of each `Tag` in that `Item` sub-set.

Is there a way to do this using the PostgreSQL 9.3 / 9.4 array operators?

My plan B is to have a separate table `Tags` and many-to-many link table `Item_Tags`, and then do a:

```
CREATE TABLE "Tags" (
  "Name" character varying,
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE "Items" (
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  data character varying,
  CONSTRAINT "Items_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE "Item_Tags" (
  tag_id uuid,
  item_id uuid,
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "Item_Tags_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "Item_Tags_item_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
      REFERENCES "Items" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT "Item_Tags_tag_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (tag_id)
  REFERENCES "Tags" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

Select "Tags"."Name", count(*)
From "Tags"
Join "Item_Tags" on "Tags"."id" = "Item_Tags"."tag_id"
Join "Items" on "Items"."id" = "Item_Tags"."item_id"
Where "Items"."data" in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e') -- replace with actual criteria
Group By "Tags"."Name"
```

Is there a better way?

Are there any special indices to use which would help make this more efficient, assuming both the `Items` and `Tags` tables are large (hundreds of millions and millions items, respectively)?

If I want counts of all tags (without filtering), should I just create a view and use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### DB schema

Your plan B is the generally superior approach (exceptions apply). But your implementation doesn't look good. Don't use non-descriptive identifiers like "id" or "name", don't use double-quoted mixed-case identifiers, etc. Consider this related answer with a "best-practice" code example:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Also, don't use [`UUID`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-uuid.html) columns if you don't have to. The data type `bigint` (use a [`bigserial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) for your pk columns!) easily covers "hundreds of millions" of rows and is much faster and smaller on disk.

#### Query

With a clean implementation, a (substantially faster) query could look like this:

For a small percentage of rows:

```
SELECT tag_id, t.tag, c.ct
FROM  (
   SELECT it.tag_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   item     i
   JOIN   item_tag it USING (item_id)
   WHERE  i.data = ANY ('{a,b,c,d,e}')    -- ANY is shorter for a long list
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c
JOIN   tag t USING (tag_id);
```

For all tags (don't join to table `item` at all):

```
SELECT tag_id, t.tag, c.ct
FROM  (
   SELECT tag_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   item_tag
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c
JOIN   tag t USING (tag_id);
```

Especially for lots of rows, it pays to aggregate before you join:

- [Why does the following join increase the query time significantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970357/why-does-the-following-join-increase-the-query-time-significantly/18971600#18971600)

#### Answers to appended questions

- Special indices may be *possible* for *special* cases - which you would have to define clearly. In particular, [partial indices](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) *might* come in handy.
- A view is not going to help performance at all. It's just a "saved query".
  A [materialized view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rules-materializedviews.html) could be very useful for read-only tables or if you do not need to include the latest changes in every result. Introduced with Postgres 9.3. [Expect further improvements from the upcoming Postgres 9.4.](http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1522/)
- If you want counts for *all tags* indexes are not going to help performance at all, since Postgres will run sequential scans when most or all of the table is involved.