# SQL How to select customers with highest transaction amount by state

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to write a SQL query that returns the name and purchase amount of the five customers in each state who have spent the most money.

Table schemas

```
customers
|_state
|_customer_id
|_customer_name

transactions
|_customer_id
|_transact_amt
```

Attempts look something like this

```
SELECT state, Sum(transact_amt) AS HighestSum
FROM (
    SELECT name, transactions.transact_amt, SUM(transactions.transact_amt) AS HighestSum
    FROM customers
    INNER JOIN customers ON transactions.customer_id = customers.customer_id
    GROUP BY state
) Q
GROUP BY transact_amt
ORDER BY HighestSum
```

I'm lost.  Thank you.

**Expected results are the names of customers with the top 5 highest transactions in each state.**

```
ERROR:  table name "customers" specified more than once
SQL state: 42712
```

Comment: In case of ties in the fifth place, do you want them all (maybe more than 5 per state), or always a max of 5?

Comment: I want to return only the top 5 for each state, thank you

Comment: How to pick "the top 5" when the top 10 spent the same amount? And please always disclose your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need for your `JOIN` to be correct.  Second, you want to use window functions:

```
SELECT ct.*
FROM (SELECT c.customer_id, c.name, c.state, SUM(t.transact_amt) AS total,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.state ORDER BY SUM(t.transact_amt) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM customers c JOIN
           transaactions t
           ON t.customer_id = c.customer_id
      GROUP BY c.customer_id, c.name, c.state
     ) ct
WHERE seqnum <= 5;
```

You seem to have several issues with SQL.  I would start with understanding aggregation functions.  You have a `SUM()` with the alias `HighestSum`.  It is simply the total per customer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get them using aggregation and then by using the `RANK()` window function. For example:

```
select
  state,
  rk,
  customer_name
from (
  select
    *,
    rank() over(partition by state order by total desc) as rk
  from (
    select
      c.customer_id,
      c.customer_name,
      c.state,
      sum(t.transact_amt) as total
    from customers c
    join transactions t on t.customer_id = c.customer_id
    group by c.customer_id
  ) x
) y
where rk <= 5
order by state, rk
```

Comment: As the question is not clear, if OP wants exactly 5 (i.e if there are 10 customers that have spent the very same amount, get only 5 of them and ignore the rest), he can replace  `rank()` with `row_number()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two valid answers already. Here's a third:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT c.state, c.customer_name, t.*
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY c.state ORDER BY t.transact_sum DESC NULLS LAST, customer_id) AS rn
   FROM  (
      SELECT customer_id, sum(transact_amt) AS transact_sum
      FROM   transactions
      GROUP  BY customer_id
      ) t
   JOIN   customers c USING (customer_id)
   ) sub
WHERE  rn < 6
ORDER  BY state, rn;
```

#### Major points

- When aggregating all or most rows of a big table, it's typically **substantially faster** to aggregate *before* the join. Assuming referential integrity (FK constraints), we won't be aggregating rows that would be filtered otherwise. This might change from nice-to-have to a pure *necessity* when joining to more aggregated tables. Related:

  - [Why does the following join increase the query time significantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970357/why-does-the-following-join-increase-the-query-time-significantly/18971600#18971600)
  - [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)
- Add additional `ORDER BY` item(s) in the window function to define **which rows to pick from ties**. In my example, it's simply `customer_id`. If you have no tiebreaker, results are arbitrary in case of a tie, which may be OK. But every other execution might return different results, which typically *is* a problem. **Or** you include all ties in the result. Then we are back to [`rank()` instead of `row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html). See:

  - [PostgreSQL equivalent for TOP n WITH TIES: LIMIT "with ties"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629953/postgresql-equivalent-for-top-n-with-ties-limit-with-ties/9630562#9630562)
- While `transact_amt` can be NULL (has not been ruled out) any sum may end up to be NULL as well. With an an unsuspecting `ORDER BY t.transact_sum DESC` those customers come out on top as NULL comes first in descending order. Use **`DESC NULLS LAST`** to avoid this pitfall. (Or define the column `transact_amt` as `NOT NULL`.)

  - [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Comment: Just want to know. The condition like `WHERE  rn < 6` means that the whole dataset (100-1000-1000000 items) should be retrieved/calculated before and only several (6) items from it will be returned by the query. Probably, using pl/pgsql could be more efficient?

Comment: @Abelisto: Well, how would you identify the top 5 *without* looking at all rows?

Comment: Some clarification: is `select * from (select row_number() over () as rn, * from sometable) as t where t.rn < 6` would be more efficient then `rn := 1; for v in select * from sometable loop return next; rn := rn + 1; if rn > 6 then break; end loop`

Comment: @Abelisto: Ah, you mean: avoid sorting the long tail? Not sure there is potential. Alternatives have expensive overhead. Also not sure whether Postgres is smart enough to optimize that automatically (and fully). A CTE *might* help with it. Might be worth a question on dba.SE ...

Comment: Yes. In the first case wee need to 1) retrieve the whole data 2) calculate some value on each row 3) filter the result on some condition related to the calculated values. And in the second case wee need 1) retrieve only the n-s rows... and that's all. It is why I do not like answers related to filters on window-functions.