# PostgreSQL function + cast in jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

How can this statement be expressed with jOOQ?

`SELECT version FROM abc ORDER BY string_to_array(version, '.', '')::int[] desc limit 1`

I am struggling with the function and cast combination.

Comment: Very interesting ordering technique, btw... Finally, a use case for arrays in PostgreSQL :-)

Comment: This is to sort version numbers directly in the DB. It's Postgres and it's awesome :-)

Comment: Yes, PostgreSQL seems to enhance the SQL:2011 standard, which specifies in `8.2 <comparison predicate>`, `General Rules`, `1) b) ii)` that the `<` comparison operation is not defined for arrays... I wonder if PostgreSQL makes such guarantees, though... [it seems to be the case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15674585/521799)

Comment: [yep, it is](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-array.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have various options.

#### Be lazy and wrap everything in a single plain SQL expression:

```java
Field<Integer[]> f1 = 
    DSL.field("string_to_array(version, '.', '')::int[]", Integer[].class);
```

#### Create a re-usable function:

```java
Field<Integer[]> stringToIntArray(Field<String> arg1, String arg2, String arg3) {
    return DSL.field("string_to_array({0}, {1}, {2})::int[]", Integer[].class,
        arg1, DSL.val(arg2), DSL.val(arg3));
}

// and then...
Field<Integer[]> f2 = stringToIntArray(ABC.VERSION, ".", "");
```

#### Use the code generator to generate the built-in function, and cast it explicitly:

```java
Field<Integer[]> f3 = Routines.stringToArray(ABC.VERSION, DSL.val("."), DSL.val(""))
                              .cast(Integer[].class);
```

The built-in function is part of the `pg_catalog` schema in the `postgres` database.

#### Put it together

```java
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(ABC.VERSION)
   .from(ABC)
   .orderBy(fN.desc()) // place any of f1, f2, f3 here
   .limit(1)
   .fetch();
```