# PostgreSQL query to count/group by day and display days with no data

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by

I need to create a PostgreSQL query that returns

- a day
- the number of objects found for that day

It's important that **every single day appear in the results**, even if no objects were found on that day. (This has been discussed before but I haven't been able to get things working in my specific case.)

First, I found a [sql query to generate a range of days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346132/postgres-how-to-return-rows-with-0-count-for-missing-data), with which I can join:

```
SELECT to_char(date_trunc('day', (current_date - offs)), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
AS date 
FROM generate_series(0, 365, 1) 
AS offs
```

Results in:

```
    date    
------------
 2013-03-28
 2013-03-27
 2013-03-26
 2013-03-25
 ...
 2012-03-28
(366 rows)
```

Now I'm trying to join that to a table named 'sharer_emailshare' which has a 'created' column:

```
Table 'public.sharer_emailshare'
column    |   type  
-------------------
id        | integer
created   | timestamp with time zone
message   | text
to        | character varying(75)
```

Here's the best `GROUP BY` query I have so far:

```
SELECT d.date, count(se.id) FROM (
    select to_char(date_trunc('day', (current_date - offs)), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AS date 
    FROM generate_series(0, 365, 1) 
    AS offs
    ) d 
JOIN sharer_emailshare se 
ON (d.date=to_char(date_trunc('day', se.created), 'YYYY-MM-DD'))  
GROUP BY d.date;
```

The results:

```
    date    | count 
------------+-------
 2013-03-27 |    11
 2013-03-24 |     2
 2013-02-14 |     2
(3 rows)
```

Desired results:

```
    date    | count 
------------+-------
 2013-03-28 |     0
 2013-03-27 |    11
 2013-03-26 |     0
 2013-03-25 |     0
 2013-03-24 |     2
 2013-03-23 |     0
 ...
 2012-03-28 |     0
(366 rows)
```

If I understand correctly this is because I'm using a plain (implied `INNER`) `JOIN`, and this is the expected behavior, as [discussed in the postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html).

I've looked through dozens of StackOverflow solutions, and all the ones with working queries seem specific to MySQL/Oracle/MSSQL and I'm having a hard time translating them to PostgreSQL.

The guy asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346132/postgres-how-to-return-rows-with-0-count-for-missing-data) found his answer, with Postgres, but put it on a pastebin link that expired some time ago.

I've tried to switch to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, use a `CASE` statement to sub in another value if null, `COALESCE` to provide a default value, etc, but I haven't been able to use them in a way that gets me what I need.

Any assistance is appreciated! And I promise I'll get around to reading that giant PostgreSQL book soon ;)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You just need a `left outer join` instead of an inner join:

```
SELECT d.date, count(se.id)
  FROM 
    (
    SELECT to_char(date_trunc('day', (current_date - offs)), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date 
       FROM generate_series(0, 365, 1) AS offs
    ) d
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sharer_emailshare se 
    ON d.date = to_char(date_trunc('day', se.created), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  GROUP BY d.date;
```

Comment: Wow, I was so close! I must have messed something up when I tried LEFT OUTER JOIN during my tests. Thank you for the swift response!

Comment: Actually, I think the problem was that I was adding a naked WHERE clause in there, which I didn't mention here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 41):

Extending Gordon Linoff's helpful answer, I would suggest a couple of improvements such as:

- Use `::date` instead of `date_trunc('day', ...)`
- Join on a date type rather than a character type (it's cleaner).
- Use specific date ranges so they're easier to change later. In this case I select a year before the most recent entry in the table - something that couldn't have been done easily with the other query.
- Compute the totals for an arbitrary subquery (using a CTE). You just have to cast the column of interest to the date type and call it date_column.
- Include a column for cumulative total. (Why not?)

Here's my query:

```
WITH dates_table AS (
    SELECT created::date AS date_column FROM sharer_emailshare WHERE showroom_id=5
)
SELECT series_table.date, COUNT(dates_table.date_column), SUM(COUNT(dates_table.date_column)) OVER (ORDER BY series_table.date) FROM (
    SELECT (last_date - b.offs) AS date
        FROM (
            SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(0, last_date - first_date, 1) AS offs, last_date from (
                 SELECT MAX(date_column) AS last_date, (MAX(date_column) - '1 year'::interval)::date AS first_date FROM dates_table
            ) AS a
        ) AS b
) AS series_table
LEFT OUTER JOIN dates_table
    ON (series_table.date = dates_table.date_column)
GROUP BY series_table.date
ORDER BY series_table.date
```

I tested the query, and it produces the same results, plus the column for cumulative total.

Comment: I like your solution :) All I had to do was copy and paste, change the CTE to my table and I was all set.

Answer (score 9):

Based on Gordon Linoff's answer I realized another problem was that I had a `WHERE` clause that I didn't mention in the original question.

Instead of a naked `WHERE`, I made a subquery:

```
SELECT d.date, count(se.id) FROM (
    select to_char(date_trunc('day', (current_date - offs)), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AS date 
    FROM generate_series(0, 365, 1) 
    AS offs
    ) d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM sharer_emailshare 
    WHERE showroom_id=5
) se
ON (d.date=to_char(date_trunc('day', se.created), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) 
GROUP BY d.date;
```

Answer (score 9):

I'll try to provide an answer that includes some explanation. I'll start with the smallest building block and work up.

If you run a query like this:

```
SELECT series.number FROM generate_series(0, 9) AS series(number)
```

You get output like this:

```
 number 
--------
      0
      1
      2
      3
      4
      5
      6
      7
      8
      9
(10 rows)
```

This can be turned into dates like this:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE + sequential_dates.date AS date
  FROM generate_series(0, 9) AS sequential_dates(date)
```

Which will give output like this:

```
    date    
------------
 2019-09-29
 2019-09-30
 2019-10-01
 2019-10-02
 2019-10-03
 2019-10-04
 2019-10-05
 2019-10-06
 2019-10-07
 2019-10-08
(10 rows)
```

Then you can do a query like this (for example), joining the original query as a subquery against whatever table you're ultimately interested in:

```
   SELECT sequential_dates.date,
          COUNT(calendar_items.*) AS calendar_item_count
     FROM (SELECT CURRENT_DATE + sequential_dates.date AS date
             FROM generate_series(0, 9) AS sequential_dates(date)) sequential_dates
LEFT JOIN calendar_items ON calendar_items.starts_at::date = sequential_dates.date
 GROUP BY sequential_dates.date
```

Which will give output like this:

```
    date    | calendar_item_count 
------------+---------------------
 2019-09-29 |                   1
 2019-09-30 |                   8
 2019-10-01 |                  15
 2019-10-02 |                  11
 2019-10-03 |                   1
 2019-10-04 |                  12
 2019-10-05 |                   0
 2019-10-06 |                   0
 2019-10-07 |                  27
 2019-10-08 |                  24
```

Comment: Generate_series has overloaded version `generate_series(start, stop, step interval)`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=69f2c72d810f3988cf4cfcb1934667e2

Answer (score 0):

I like Jason Swett SQL however ran into issue where the count on some dates should be a zero rather than a one.
Running the statment select count(*) from public.post_call_info where timestamp::date = '2020-11-23' count = zero, but below equals a one.

Also the + give me a forward schedule so changed to a minus provide 9 days data prior to current date.

```
SELECT sequential_dates.date,
COUNT(*) AS call_count
FROM (SELECT CURRENT_DATE - sequential_dates.date AS date
        FROM generate_series(0, 9) AS sequential_dates(date)) sequential_dates
LEFT JOIN public.post_call_info ON public.post_call_info.timestamp::date = 
    sequential_dates.date
GROUP BY sequential_dates.date
    order by date desc
```

Comment: found this issue now - under count add the schema and table.*. this fixed the count problem. Now shows 0

Comment: SELECT sequential_dates.date,
          COUNT(public.post_call_info.*) AS call_count
     FROM (SELECT CURRENT_DATE - sequential_dates.date AS date
             FROM generate_series(0, 9) AS sequential_dates(date)) sequential_dates
LEFT JOIN public.post_call_info ON public.post_call_info.timestamp::date = sequential_dates.date
 GROUP BY sequential_dates.date
 order by date desc