# Postgres monthly balance

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, generate-series

I'm using postgreSQL 9.2
I have a table with transactions that affect an account startbalance and I want to create a query that generates the monthly balances. It seems simple, but I'm stuck and the closest thing I can find might be this [Calculate Monthly Recurring Revenue(MRR) result using postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191761/calculate-monthly-recurring-revenuemrr-result-using-postgres)
because it uses generate_series, which I think I need to create a list of the months to match up my accounts and transactions.

Here is the DDL for my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  startbalance numeric(19,2),
  opendate date NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE trx (
 id integer NOT NULL,
 accountid integer NOT NULL,
 amount numeric(19,2) NOT NULL,
 transactiondate date NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE ONLY account
 ADD CONSTRAINT account_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY trx
 ADD CONSTRAINT transaction_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY trx
 ADD CONSTRAINT transaction_accountid_fk FOREIGN KEY (accountid) REFERENCES account(id);
```

And the data:

```
INSERT INTO account VALUES (1, 200.00, '2016-01-01');
INSERT INTO account VALUES (2, 400.00, '2016-03-02');
INSERT INTO account VALUES (3, 800.00, '2016-01-15');

INSERT INTO trx VALUES (1, 1, -100.00, '2016-01-10');
INSERT INTO trx VALUES (6, 2, -200.00, '2016-03-25');
INSERT INTO trx VALUES (9, 3, -400.00, '2016-02-03');
INSERT INTO trx VALUES (8, 2, -100.00, '2016-09-15');
INSERT INTO trx VALUES (5, 1, -20.00, '2016-06-20');
INSERT INTO trx VALUES (3, 1, -20.00, '2016-03-04');
INSERT INTO trx VALUES (2, 1, -10.00, '2016-02-02');
INSERT INTO trx VALUES (10, 3, -100.00, '2016-04-12');
INSERT INTO trx VALUES (11, 3, -100.00, '2016-04-25');
INSERT INTO trx VALUES (12, 3, -200.00, '2016-04-29');
INSERT INTO trx VALUES (4, 1, -50.00, '2016-06-05');
INSERT INTO trx VALUES (7, 2, -100.00, '2016-08-05');
```

I've figured out how to use the window function to get running totals for each transaction:

```
SELECT 
  acct.id accountid,
  acct.startbalance,
  amount,
  transactiondate,
  acct.startbalance + sum(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY acct.id ORDER BY transactiondate) balance
FROM 
account acct 
LEFT JOIN trx ON trx.accountid = acct.id 
ORDER BY transactiondate DESC
```

This gives me:

```
accountid opendate startbalance amount transactiondate balance
2   2016-03-02  400.00  -100.00 2016-09-15  0.00
2   2016-03-02  400.00  -100.00 2016-08-05  100.00
1   2016-01-01  200.00  -20.00  2016-06-20  0.00
1   2016-01-01  200.00  -50.00  2016-06-05  20.00
3   2016-01-15  800.00  -200.00 2016-04-29  0.00
3   2016-01-15  800.00  -100.00 2016-04-25  200.00
3   2016-01-15  800.00  -100.00 2016-04-12  300.00
2   2016-03-02  400.00  -200.00 2016-03-25  200.00
1   2016-01-01  200.00  -20.00  2016-03-04  70.00
3   2016-01-15  800.00  -400.00 2016-02-03  400.00
1   2016-01-01  200.00  -10.00  2016-02-02  90.00
1   2016-01-01  200.00  -100.00 2016-01-10  100.00
```

but it doesn't show anything for the months with no data. What I need is something more like a resultset that shows data for each month in a range (e.g. 1/2016 - 6/2016):

```
MonthOf AcctId  OrigBal Pmt     Balance
2016-06     3   800     0       0
2016-06     2   400     0       200
2016-06     1   200     -70     0
2016-05     3   800     0       0
2016-05     2   400     0       200
2016-05     1   200     0       70
2016-04     3   800     -400    0
2016-04     2   400     0       200
2016-04     1   200     0       70
2016-03     3   800     -400    400
2016-03     2   400     -200    200
2016-03     1   200     -20     70
2016-02     3   800     -400    400
2016-02     2   0       0       0
2016-02     1   200     -10     90
2016-01     3   800     0       800
2016-01     2   0       0       0
2016-01     1   200     -100    100
```

I tried examples joining a CTE with a generate_series statement, but couldn't get the expected results. Below is the generate_series result I tried to put in a cte. I couldn't get the balances to add up correctly. I'm new to window functions, so I'm sure there's just something I'm missing or maybe I'm just working down the wrong path.

```
SELECT  
date_trunc('month', dates) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 SECOND' end_of_month
FROM 
generate_series('2016-01-01'::timestamp, '2016-6-24'::timestamp, '1 month'::interval) dates
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a window function (maybe a bit ugly, but it appears to work ...) :

Note: I am ignoring the `account.opendate`, since it is not relevant for the summing.

---

UPDATE: *unborn* accounts are handled in the WHILE clause, now

---

```
WITH cal AS ( -- calender table
        SELECT generate_series('2016-01-01'::date, '2016-10-01'::date , '1 month'::interval)::date dt
        )
SELECT
        a.id, a.startbalance
        , c.dt
        , COALESCE(t.cumsum, 0.0)::NUMERIC(19,2) AS cumsum
        , a.startbalance + COALESCE(t.cumsum, 0.0)::NUMERIC(19,2) AS balance
FROM cal c
CROSS JOIN account a
LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( -- aggregating subquery
        SELECT accountid
        , SUM(amount) AS cumsum
        FROM trx
        WHERE transactiondate < c.dt
        GROUP BY accountid
        ) t ON t.accountid = a.id
WHERE a.opendate <= c.dt -- suppress unborn accounts
ORDER BY a.id, c.dt
        ;
```

---

Update: we can avoid the `LATERAL` by an ordinary old-fashioned scalar subquery.

---

```
WITH cal AS ( -- calender table
    SELECT generate_series('2016-01-01', '2016-10-01' , '1 month'::interval)::date dt
    )
, xxx AS ( -- grid table
    SELECT a.startbalance , a.id AS accountid , c.dt AS xdt
    FROM cal c -- in fact a cross join ...
    JOIN account a ON a.opendate <= c.dt
    )
SELECT
    x.accountid, x.startbalance, x.xdt
    , (SELECT SUM(t.amount) FROM trx t
        WHERE t.accountid = x.accountid
        AND t.transactiondate <= x.xdt) AS cumsum
    , COALESCE(x.startbalance
             + (SELECT SUM(t.amount) FROM trx t
               WHERE t.accountid = x.accountid
               AND t.transactiondate <= x.xdt)
         , x.startbalance) AS balance
FROM xxx x
ORDER BY x.accountid, x.xdt
        ;
```

Comment: That's a great answer, if I was using 9.3+ (when lateral joins were introduced).
I'm stuck with 9.2. 
Thanks in Advance, if you can come up with something else!

Comment: Ah! I was just posting a solution I came up with. Our solutions are different, but yours seems more simple with the subqueries in the columns. I was trying too hard to think outside the box.
-edit, the results from this query are slightly different because I wanted to get all payments for that month. Changing the subquery filter to : date_trunc('month',t.transactiondate) <= x.xdt for both columns did the trick. 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This has given me results I can work with:

```
WITH dates AS (

    SELECT  
    date_trunc('month', dates) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 SECOND' end_of_month
    FROM 
    generate_series('2016-01-01'::timestamp, '2016-6-24'::timestamp, '1 month'::interval) dates
)


SELECT 
date_trunc('month', dates.end_of_month) endofmonth,
acct.id accountid,
acct.opendate,
acct.startbalance,
acct.startbalance + (SUM(sum(COALESCE(trx.amount, 0))) OVER (PARTITION BY acct.id ORDER BY dates.end_of_month)) balance
FROM 
dates
LEFT join account acct ON date_trunc('month', dates.end_of_month) >= date_trunc('month',acct.opendate)
LEFT JOIN trx ON trx.accountid = acct.id AND date_trunc('month', trx.transactionDate) = date_trunc('month', dates.end_of_month) 
GROUP BY 
dates.end_of_month,
acct.id,
acct.opendate,
acct.startbalance
ORDER BY endofmonth DESC, acct.id DESC
```