# Use PostreSQL 9.3 to calculate Monthly Recurring Revenue (MRR), by customer

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've found a few answers that can get me close [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253137/postgres-monthly-balance) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191761/calculate-monthly-recurring-revenuemrr-result-using-postgres), but not exactly what I'm looking for.

Here's the sample data set

```
CREATE TABLE invoices
(
    "start" date,
    "end" date,
    custid int,
    amt float
);

INSERT INTO invoices
VALUES ('2021-02-01', '2022-01-31', 1, 10),
       ('2021-03-01', '2021-03-31', 2, 20)
;  
       
select * from invoices
```

| start | end | custid | amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | 2022-01-31 | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-31 | 2 | 20 |

The ideal output would generate the series for each customer like the table below

| month | custid | amt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-28 | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-03-31 | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-04-30 | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-05-31 | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-06-30 | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-07-31 | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-08-31 | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-09-30 | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-10-31 | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-11-30 | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-12-31 | 1 | 10 |
| 2022-01-31 | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-03-31 | 2 | 20 |

I'm assuming this will require the `generate_series` function, but quite sure how to proceed.

**Edit**: spelled out MRR in the title so we're all on the same page.

**Edit 2**: The code block below seems to work, but still very interested in other approaches that might be more efficient

```
CREATE TABLE invoices
(
    "start" date,
    "end" date,
    custid int,
    amt float
);

INSERT INTO invoices
VALUES ('2021-02-01', '2022-01-31', 1, 10),
       ('2021-03-01', '2021-03-31', 2, 20)
;  
       
WITH cal AS ( -- calender table
        SELECT generate_series('2021-02-01'::date, '2022-01-31'::date , '1 month'::interval)::date dt
        )
SELECT
        a.custid, a.amt
        ,a.start
        ,a.end
        ,c.dt
FROM cal c
CROSS JOIN invoices a
where a.start <= c.dt and a.end >=c.dt
order by a.custid, c.dt
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0a28f1/165)

Comment: Edited , see title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `generate_series` to create a table of months:

```
SELECT (s.d + '1 month')::date - 1 AS month,
       i.custid,
       i.amt
FROM invoices AS i
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(
                         date_trunc('month', i.start::timestamp),
                         i.end::timestamp,
                         '1 month'
                      ) AS s(d)
ORDER BY i.custid, s.d;

   month    │ custid │ amt 
════════════╪════════╪═════
 2021-02-28 │      1 │  10
 2021-03-31 │      1 │  10
 2021-04-30 │      1 │  10
 2021-05-31 │      1 │  10
 2021-06-30 │      1 │  10
 2021-07-31 │      1 │  10
 2021-08-31 │      1 │  10
 2021-09-30 │      1 │  10
 2021-10-31 │      1 │  10
 2021-11-30 │      1 │  10
 2021-12-31 │      1 │  10
 2022-01-31 │      1 │  10
 2021-03-31 │      2 │  20
(13 rows)
```

Comment: AHHHH, this seems to be much more efficient than my attempt.

Comment: Question, what does the 's(d)' mean in postgresql/sql?

Comment: It is an alias for the result of the table function.

Comment: I'm playing with this in SQL Fiddle. If the dates in my second record move a few days to let's say start=3/14/21 and end=4/14/21, I get similar results (i.e., month=4/13/21 instead of 4/30/21), but not the same. If I wanted the exact output, how would I modify this?

Comment: Perhaps you need `date_trunc`.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0a28f1/224 solved it I think