# Postgres SQL - Add empty tuples when grouping query by hour

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg

I am writing a query to group events by hour on a table. My problem is that during hours in which there was no activity, no line is shown for them

For example I am getting:

```
|2015-04-07 08:00:00 | 2
|2015-04-07 09:00:00 | 1
|2015-04-07 11:00:00 | 1
```

when I would like to add an empty row with 0 values for hours in which no data exists:

```
|2015-04-07 08:00:00 | 2
|2015-04-07 09:00:00 | 1
|2015-04-07 10:00:00 | 0  <-- ADD EMPTY ROW
|2015-04-07 11:00:00 | 1
```

My query is:

```
   SELECT date_trunc('hour', "timeStarted"::timestamp) as "DATE STARTED", COUNT(*) 
FROM session s 
WHERE "timeStarted" BETWEEN timestamp with time zone '2015-04-07 00:00:00+01' AND timestamp with time zone '2015-04-07 23:59:00+01'
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', "timeStarted"::timestamp) 
ORDER BY "DATE STARTED"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL query to count/group by day and display days with no data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691127/postgresql-query-to-count-group-by-day-and-display-days-with-no-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with function `generate_series`. [PostgreSQL documentation  - 9.24. Set Returning Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html):

```
SELECT generate_series, COUNT("timeStarted") 
FROM generate_series('2015-04-07 00:00:00+01', '2015-04-07 23:59:00+01', '1 hour'::interval)
LEFT JOIN session s ON date_trunc('hour', "timeStarted"::timestamp) = generate_series
    AND "timeStarted" BETWEEN timestamp with time zone '2015-04-07 00:00:00+01' AND timestamp with time zone '2015-04-07 23:59:00+01'
    GROUP BY generate_series
ORDER BY generate_series;
```

Note that the explicitly stated time range on `timeStarted` in the JOIN condition is redundant. If index is used on `timeStarted` the explicit time range makes sure that it is being used in the query (if deemed so by the query planner).

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at outer joins, this is a LOT simpler!