# Count data per day in a specific month in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, count, each

I have a table with a create date called `created_at` and a delete date called `delete_at` for each record. If the record was deleted, the field save that date; it's a logic delete.

I need to count the `active records` in a specific month. To understand what is an `active record` for me, let's see an example:

For this example we'll use this hypothetical record:

```
id | created_at | deleted_at
1  | 23-01-2014 | 05-06-2014
```

This record is active for every days between its creation date and delete date. Including that last. So if I need count the active record for March, in this case, this record must be counted in every days of that month.

I have a query (really easy to do) that show the actives records for a specific month, but my principal problem is how to count that actives for each day in that month.

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('day', created_at) AS dia_creacion,
  date_trunc('day', deleted_at) AS dia_eliminacion
FROM
  myTable
WHERE
  created_at < TO_DATE('01-04-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
  AND (deleted_at IS NULL OR deleted_at >= TO_DATE('01-03-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY'))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL query to count/group by day and display days with no data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691127/postgresql-query-to-count-group-by-day-and-display-days-with-no-data)

Comment: That's a solution for a simple count of records. In this case we must remember the `active records`.

Comment: What is the expected output you want to have? Just the number of days?

Comment: I expected as output the number of `active records` per day.

Comment: I think it's the same solution and all you need is a diffrent join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
select 
  TO_DATE('01-03-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + g.i, 
  count( case (TO_DATE('01-03-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + g.i) between created_at and coalesce(deleted_at, TO_DATE('01-03-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + g.i)
    when true then 1
    else null
  end)
from generate_series(0, TO_DATE('01-04-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') - TO_DATE('01-03-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) as g(i)
left join myTable on true
group by 1
order by 1;
```

You can add more specific condition for joining only relevant records from `myTable`, but even without it gives you idea how to achieve counting as desired.