# How to add missing timestamps into data in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql

Similar to this question - [Postgres - how to return rows with 0 count for missing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346132/postgres-how-to-return-rows-with-0-count-for-missing-data)

I have a table to tack number of users used my service per day. I record it by timestamps and user ID.
Current query -

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', recorded_at), COUNT(log_id) AS daily_count FROM uses_tracker 
WHERE log_id = 15183 AND recorded_at >= now() - INTERVAL '30 DAYS' GROUP BY 1
```

It returns me the data in this format -

```
date_trunc                   daily_count
2021-04-01 00:00:00.000000      2
2021-04-06 00:00:00.000000      1
```

Expected Format -

```
date_trunc                   daily_count
2021-04-01 00:00:00.000000      2
2021-04-02 00:00:00.000000      0
2021-04-03 00:00:00.000000      0
2021-04-04 00:00:00.000000      0
2021-04-05 00:00:00.000000      0
2021-04-06 00:00:00.000000      1
```

the data which i am getting currently is because other timestamps are not inserted in DB. How to add the missing one's while querying the data?

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a series of dates for last 30 days and then left join your table on date of the series and count. Try something like

```
SELECT date, COUNT(ut.log_id) AS daily_count
FROM (
 SELECT date_trunc('day', dd)::date as date
 FROM generate_series
  ( now() - INTERVAL '30 DAYS'
  , now()
  , '1 day'::interval) dd
 ) dates
LEFT JOIN uses_tracker ut on ut.recorded_at::date = dates.date
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Hello thanks i did tried. But it's still not returning those Rows..just returning the one with values. Query is same as yours. Any idea on how to assign 0 if it doesn't exist?

Comment: I did - 
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', recorded_at), COUNT(log_id) AS daily_count
FROM uses_tracker ut
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT date_trunc('day', dd):: date
 FROM generate_series
 ( now() - INTERVAL '30 DAYS'
 , now()
 , '1 day'::interval) dd
) as dates on dates.date = ut.recorded_at::date
WHERE log_id = 15183
GROUP BY 1

Says - column dates.date does not exist

Comment: When i do this i get - '(', ',', CROSS, EXCEPT, FETCH, FOR, FULL, GROUP, HAVING, INNER, INTERSECT, JOIN, LEFT, LIMIT, NATURAL, OFFSET, ORDER, RIGHT, TABLESAMPLE, UNION, WHERE or WINDOW expected, got 'd'

So i did this -
SELECT d.date, COUNT(ut.log_id) AS daily_count
FROM (
 SELECT date_trunc('day', dd):: date
 FROM generate_series
  ( now() - INTERVAL '30 DAYS'
  , now()
  , '1 day'::interval) dd
 ) as d
JOIN uses_tracker ut on ut.recorded_at::date = d.date
GROUP BY 1

And i still get - [42703] ERROR: column d.date does not exist Position: 244

Comment: Didn't wanted to spam comment section so here's the link https://mystb.in/InterpretedCraftGreat.sql
Still error

Comment: alias was misspelled in the join statement. must be okay now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231049/discussion-between-prashant-and-adil-khalil).