# Inner join generation series with "with clause" to populate missing dates as null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the postgres statement below.

```
WITH dailyhh as (
    SELECT distinct on(settlement_period_id) t1.estimated_consumption, t1.settlement_date,t1.annualised_consumption,
        rank() OVER (
            PARTITION BY settlement_period_id
                ORDER BY
                    CASE settlement_period_interval_count
                        WHEN 0 THEN 1
                        ELSE 2
                    END
        )
    FROM consumption_db_schema.halfhourlyconsumption t1
    where t1.mprn = '123456789'
    and t1.settlement_time between '2021-01-01' and '2021-12-31'
    )
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', settlement_date) as settle,
    sum(estimated_consumption) as sum_estimated,
    sum(annualised_consumption) as sum_annualiseds
FROM dailyhh
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month', settlement_date)
ORDER BY settle ASC;
```

I need to return null if there is no values in that date period. For instance the provides the table below:

| settle timestamp with time zone | sum_estimated numeric | sum_annualiseds numeric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z | null | 713.2 |
| 2021-11-01T00:00:00.000Z | null | 981.0 |
| 2021-12-01T00:00:00.000Z | null | 992.3 |

However, I need a table which provides null for the missing dates, i.e

| settle timestamp with time zone | sum_estimated numeric | sum_annualiseds numeric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | null | null |
| 2021-02-01T00:00:00.000Z | null | null |
| 2021-03-01T00:00:00.000Z | null | null |
| 2021-04-01T00:00:00.000Z | null | null |
| 2021-05-01T00:00:00.000Z | null | null |
| 2021-06-01T00:00:00.000Z | null | null |
| 2021-07-01T00:00:00.000Z | null | null |
| 2021-08-01T00:00:00.000Z | null | null |
| 2021-09-01T00:00:00.000Z | null | null |
| 2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z | null | 713.2 |
| 2021-11-01T00:00:00.000Z | null | 981 |
| 2021-12-01T00:00:00.000Z | null | 992.3 |

I have tried using the code from [How to return rows with 0 count for missing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346132/how-to-return-rows-with-0-count-for-missing-data)

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT day::date
   FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2007-12-01'
                        , timestamp '2008-12-01'
                        , interval  '1 month') day
   ) d
```

but how would one inner join with the "with clause" to get the desired table?

Comment: I don't see an actual problem statement here.  Also, why did you tag with MySQL, given that your very question makes it clear you are using Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`generate_series` to generate a range of days, then you only have to do is to `left join` this generated range by the output data coming from `dailyhh` :

```
WITH dailyhh as (
    SELECT distinct on(settlement_period_id) t1.estimated_consumption, t1.settlement_date,t1.annualised_consumption,
        rank() OVER (
            PARTITION BY settlement_period_id
                ORDER BY
                    CASE settlement_period_interval_count
                        WHEN 0 THEN 1
                        ELSE 2
                    END
        )
    FROM halfhourlyconsumption t1
    where t1.mprn = '123456789'
    and t1.settlement_time between '2021-01-01' and '2021-12-31'
)
select day as settle, s.sum_estimated, s.sum_annualiseds from (
  SELECT day::date
  FROM generate_series(date '2021-01-01', date '2021-12-31', interval  '1 month') day
) as dayrange
left join (
  SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', settlement_date) as settle,
    sum(estimated_consumption) as sum_estimated,
    sum(annualised_consumption) as sum_annualiseds
  FROM dailyhh
  GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month', settlement_date)
  ORDER BY settle ASC
) as s on dayrange.day = s.settle
```

Comment: why does replacing "month" with week, cause all of the values to be null?

Comment: This logic will not work for week intervall, an other logic should be done to make it works.